# Retrieve Pandas dataframe rows that its column (one) values are consecutively equal to the values of a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

How do I retrieve Pandas dataframe rows that its column (one) values are consecutively equal to the values of a list?

Example, given this:

```
import pandas as pd     

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 88, 99, 30, 40, 50]})

lst = [30, 40, 50]
```

I want to extract the dataframe rows from 30 to 50, but just the first sequence of consecutive values (just the 2 to 4 index rows).

Comment: Any particular reason why latter 30, 40, 50 are not required? It will in creating general code.

Comment: This is a requirement.

Comment: Is Index value required? Using Drop Duplicate can be utilised

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 88, 99, 30, 40, 50]})
lst = [30, 40, 50]
ans=[]
for i,num in enumerate(df['col1']):
    if num in lst:
        lst.remove(num)
        ans.append(i)

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a rolling comparison:

```
s = df['col1'][::-1].rolling(len(lst)).apply(lambda x: x.eq(lst[::-1]).all())[::-1].eq(1)

if s.any():
    idx = s.idxmax()
    out = df.iloc[idx:idx+len(lst)]
    print(out)
else:
    print('Not found')
```

output:

```
   col1
2    30
3    40
4    50
```

Comment: @Marco there was a missing character (copy/paste error?)

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a copy/paste error, I've deleted my comment. Your code looks great, thank you very much, but I'm just going to upvote your answer since I've already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
lst = [30, 40, 50]

if any(lst == (found := s).to_list() for s in df["col1"].rolling(len(lst))):
    print(df.loc[found.index])
```

Prints:

```
   col1
2    30
3    40
4    50
```

Comment: I couldn't run your code because an syntax error occurs when trying to interpret the Walrus operator, as I'm using Python version < 3.8. How can one change this operator by another expression to make it work in Python version < 3.8? Thanks.